# Can we reduce Tab.Navigator swipe sensitivity

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-top-tabs

My app consists of material-top-tabs navigation, with each screen containing a WebView.

I want my material-top-tabs to be navigated by swipe gesture, but the swipe is so sensitive it renders vertical scroll of web pages inside WebViews virtually impossible.

Is there a way to reduce this Tab.Navigator swipe sensitivity?